# xargs -a [file] mv -t [new-directory] gives me mv: cannot stat `filename*': No such file or directory error

Tags: shell, xargs, mv

I have been trying to run this command (that I have run before in a different directory), and everything I've read on the message boards has not solved my unknown issue.

Of note: 1) the files exist in this directory 2) I have proper permissions to move these files around 3) I have run this exact line of code before and it has worked. 4) I tried listing files with and without '*' to capture all the files (see below). 5) I also tired to list each file as 'Sample1*', but that did not work.

```
xargs -a [filename.txt] mv -t [new-directory]
```

I have file beginnings (I have ~5 file for each beginning), and I want to move all the files associated with that beginning.

Example: Sample1.bam Sample1.sorted.bam, etc
The lines in the file are listed as such:
Sample1*
Sample2*
Sample3* ...etc.

What am I doing incorrectly and how can I fix it?
TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute command using 'xargs' arguments are passed directly to the called program ('mv' in your case). Wildcard patterns in the input are not expanded - '`sample1*`' is passed as is to "mv", which issue an error message about note having a file named '`sample1*`'.

To get file name expansion, you want to use the shell. One way to handle this situation is

```
xargs -a FILENAME.TXT -I__ sh -c "mv -t NEW-FOLDER -- __"
```

**Security Note**: the code provides some protection against command line injection  (e.g., file name starting with '-').  However, other possible attacks are possible. Safer version is

```
cat FILENAME.txt | grep '^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Z-z0-9._-]*$' | xargs I__ sh -c "mv -t NEW-FOLDER -- __"
```

which will limit the input to file with alphanumeric. The 'grep' patterns can be extend the pattern as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight! It makes total sense. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you would do something like:

```
cat FILENAME.txt | parallel mv {} NEW-FOLDER
```

One of the benefits of GNU Parallel is that it deals correctly with file names like:

```
My brother's 12" records cost > $1000.txt
```